# Should single micro-service listen to single azure bus topic/queue?

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus

We have a Azure service fabric micro-service which listen to multiple azure service bus topics(Topic A, Topic B).

Topic A has more then 10 times message traffic then topic B. and to handle the scale-ability of service we will create the multiple instance of service.

1. My first question is, In most of the services instance will not get the message in Topic B, As Topic B has less traffic, So will it be waste of resources ?

2 Is it better to create different micro-services for Topic A and Topic B listeners, and create 10x instance of micro-service which listen to topic A and x instance of topic B listener service ?

3. Is create a message listener in azure service bus, keep on pulling message every time ? means continuously looking/ checking for message, message is there or not.

Thanks Guys for your supports.

Answer (score 0):

1. If one service receives messages from 2 topics, there's little waste of resources. Listening for messages is not a very resource intensive process.
2. This depends on your application requirements.
3. This depends on whether you are using SBMP / [SOAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.transporttype?view=azure-dotnet) (default) or [AMQP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide) as the communication protocol. [AMQP](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp-bindmap/amqp-wsb/v1.0/cs01/amqp-wsb-v1.0-cs01.html#_Toc461801616) is connection based. SBMP does (long) polling.

Answer (score 0):

Microservices advocates the idea of loosely coupled services, where each micro-service will handle his own domain.

Following the microservices approach, if you understand that you had to create two different topics to publish your messages, probably it is because they have different scopes\domain, needing their own micro-service.

In your description it is hard to identify if the domain of TopicA and TopicB are related, so we can not offer a good suggestion.

In any case, if one service listen for both topics, let's assume TopicA handles 1000 messages and TopicB handles 100 per second.
In case you have to publish a new version of your application to handle changes on TopicB messages, you would have to stop the handling of TopicA, that was not necessary. So you are coupling the services, that to begin with should be two independent services, or both topics should be handle as a single one.

Regarding your questions:

> 1 My first question is, In most of the services instance will not get
>   the message in Topic B, As Topic B has less traffic, So will it be
>   waste of resources ?

Waste of resources is relative how you design your application, it might be if your service listen the queue\topic and handle it at the same time, and uses too much memory to keep running all the time. In this scenario, would be case to split them and make a **Queue\Topic Listener** and other **Message Handler** that will receive the message to process, and if it keep too long without processing messages you shut it down, leaving just the listener. You could also use actors instead of a service.

> 2 Is it better to create different micro-services for Topic A and
>   Topic B listeners, and create 10x instance of micro-service which
>   listen to topic A and x instance of topic B listener service ?

Yes for the services, regarding the the number of instances, it should be driven by the size of the queue, otherwise you would have too much listeners and also wasting resources, if you follow the approach of splitting the services, you would need one listener receiving the messages from the queue\topic and it would delivery the messages to multiple messages handlers(service instances\actors) and the queue\topic listener control the number of running instances at same time.

> 3 Is create a message listener in azure service bus, keep on pulling
>   message every time ? means continuously looking/ checking for message,
>   message is there or not.

Is not the only approach, but it's correct.